# Set of poinwise convergence of a sequence of weak* continuous linear functionals is weak* closed?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $\{\Lambda_n\}$ be a sequence of weak* cont. linear functionals on $X^{*},$ the dual of a Banach space $X.$ As every weak* cont. functinal is also norm continuous on $X^{*},$ assume that the family is also uniformly bounded that is $||\Lambda_n||_{X^{*}}\leq1\forall n\in\mathbb{N}.$ Consider the set 
$$A:=\{\varphi\in X^{*}:\lim\Lambda_n\varphi\,\,\text{exists}\}.$$

The set $A$ is norm closed in $X^{*}.$ I have the following question;

Is $A$ weak* closed also?

Comment: A weak star continuous linear functional on $X^*$ can be seen as an element of $X$. You need to rewrite the details of your question.

Comment: Yes, I did try that although I'm not sure how it's going to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not true. For a counterexample, take
$X = \ell^1$, $X^* = \ell^\infty$. Define $\Lambda_n \in X^{**}$ by
$$\Lambda_n(x) = x_n$$
for $x \in \ell^\infty$. Then, it is easy to see that this sequence $\{\lambda_n\}$ satisfies your assumptions. Moreover,
$$A = \{x \in \ell^\infty: \lim_{n \to \infty} x_n \text{ exists}\}.$$
This set is not weak-$*$ closed. In fact, the set
$$c_0 = \{x \in \ell^\infty : \lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = 0\}$$
is already weak-$*$ dense in $\ell^\infty$.

Comment: But $A$ contains $c_0,$ so it is also weak* dense in $l^{\infty}?$

Comment: Yes. And, obviously, $A \ne \ell^\infty$. Hence, it cannot be weak-$*$ closed.